# undefined when using useRef and scroll event of window? - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a navbar with position sticky and when I go up to top 0 I change the color, using useRef, I apply a class .ToolbarSticky when the getBoundingClientRect().top is 0, that is, it is up, although it works it gives me an error for undefined as seen in the console

[image: 1]

this is my code

```js
import { memo, useRef } from 'react';
import styles from '../styles/NotesToolbar.module.css';
import FilterSelect from './FilterSelect';
import NotesCounter from './NotesCounter';

const NotesToolbar = () => {
  const toolbarRef = useRef();

  window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    if (toolbarRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().top <= 0) {
      toolbarRef.current.classList.add(styles.ToolbarSticky);
    } else {
      toolbarRef.current.classList.remove(styles.ToolbarSticky);
    }
  });

  return (
    <div className={styles.Toolbar} ref={toolbarRef}>
      <div className={styles.ToolbarLeft}>
        <FilterSelect />
      </div>
      <div className={styles.ToolbarRight}>
        <NotesCounter />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default memo(NotesToolbar);
```

Comment: Please provide more context, how did you use `useRef`, `getBooundingClientRect`, etc.

Comment: I forgot to put the code in the question, but I already updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things about your code
First - you should have the event listener inside a useEffect and cleanup after the component unrenders or you will have tons of eventListeners

Nest - ref is defined (or assigned) to the dom element just before render. So ref will be undefined at first. A simple check `if(ref.current) do_stuff` will fix it.

```
  useEffect(() => {
     window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler);
     return(() => window.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler);
  }, [])
```

You can define the `scrollHandler` function inside or outside the effect (but if function is heavy, outside would be better)

```
const scrollHandler = () => {
  if (toolbarRef.current) {
    if (toolbarRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().top <= 0) {
      toolbarRef.current.classList.add(styles.ToolbarSticky);
    } else {
      toolbarRef.current.classList.remove(styles.ToolbarSticky);
    }
}
```